# Excel (pivot) diagram to connect dots in a curvediagram no matter if an entry is missing

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have this pivot diagram, and I want to make a nice curve diagram, but I have some different entry points. For instance I have an entry for 3 of my series on 2008-november, but not for the fourth, which means that series 4 just stops at 2008-oktober and then begins anew on 2008-december, but I want the diagram to connect 2008-oktober with 2008-december.

is that possible? And I know that a hack would be to insert a fake data point, but I can't do that since;

1. It's a huge amount of data
2. it would give wrong data

Comment: @pnuts - I thought it was a fix, and it does help the pivotchart, but when I copy and paste it, the new fixed chart is showing the zero datapoints anyway. any ideas?